# UITableView(rows can be added or removed): make even/odd rows to have different colors?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I need to have white background for even rows and black background for odd rows, I am thinking:

Method 1:
add a property to the cell, indicating the position of the cell when presented, so the cell can switch color,
or when I return the cell, I can check its position and switch its color

- this should simply work
- need to reload whole table when a row is removed/added

Method 2:
add a stretchable background image, that has repeatedly black and white strips, since the row height is fixed, then somehow make it scrolls with the table

- this sounds smarter than method 1
- this may need to have a very large background image if the table view is big

is there any other way for doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you set the background by checking if row is odd or even.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
    ........
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)  //even
    {
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Black"]];


    }
    else
    {
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"White"]];
    }
```

Comment: While this code is appropriate, the answer doesn't actually deal with the issue of rows being inserted or removed. Adding or removing a row requires a shift in the colors of the visible rows.

Comment: You mean you want the colors to be constant while rows are scrolled? like first visble row is always white second is always black and so on?

Comment: No. Think about what happens if you were to call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` on the table view at add one row. Suddenly, all of the even rows below the insertion point need to become the odd rows. Simply calling `reloadData` will work but it will ruin any row animation you might have for the insertion.

Answer (score 1):

All of the other answers so far seem to be ignoring the issue related to inserting and removing rows.

I think the easiest approach is when you insert or remove a row, reload all of the visible rows below the insertion/deletion point. There's no need to deal with rows below the visible range.

Let's say you have 100 rows and you are viewing rows 20-30. The even rows are white as you stated. Now if a row is inserted/removed at row 35 there is nothing to do since all affected rows are off screen. If a row inserted/removed at row 25 it will show up immediately in the correct color. You now need to reload rows 26-30 so they get updated with the proper new colors. If a row is inserted/removed at row 15, you need to reload rows 20-30 (all visible rows).

You can do some optimizations if you need to. For example, if two rows are added (say at 15 and 16, then there is nothing to do.

The basic algorithm is to call `[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]` after doing the insertion/deletion. Then reload each of those paths if the path is after the inserted/removed index path.

Comment: If I do that reload on adding and removing rows, how will the animation look like?

Comment: Depends on the animation you choose to use with the `UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method. You are not reloading the whole table so the animation for the insertion/deletion shouldn't be affected.

Comment: Let me ask a doubt. When we are reloading a table only visible rows get reloaded rt? So why do we need optimization?

Comment: If you call `reloadData`, any row animations for the current insertion/deletion get lost. `reloadData` will work, but it is less efficient and it ruins pending cell animations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can check for indexpath like `indexpath%3 == 0` and add background colour to cell for method 1 like                              `cell.backroundcolor = [UIColor bluecolor];`

And add backgroun image for cell like for method 2
    `cell.bakgroundView = [UIImageview alloc]inithWitImage:[UIImage imagenamed@"cellBG.png"]];`